# How to submit in-memory images to Visual Recognition using Python

Tags: python, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I'm working for the first time with IBM Watson Visual Recognition. My Python app needs to pass images that it's managing in memory to the service. However, the rather limited documentation and sample code I've been able to find from IBM shows calls to the API as referencing saved files. The file is passed to the call as an io.BufferedReader.

```
with open(car_path, 'rb') as images_file:
    car_results = service.classify(
        images_file=images_file,
        threshold='0.1',
        classifier_ids=['default']
    ).get_result()
```

My application will be working with images from memory and I don't want to have to save every image to file before I can make a call. I tried replacing the BufferedReader with an io.BytesIO stream, and I got back an error saying I was missing an images_filename param. When I added a mock filename (e.g. 'xyz123.jpg') I get back the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'float'
```

Can I make calls to the analysis API using an image from memory? If so, how?

EDIT:

This is essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
def analyze_image(pillow_img: PIL.Image):
    byte_stream = io.BytesIO()
    pillow_img.save(byte_stream, format='JPEG')
    bytes_img = byte_stream.getvalue()

    watson_vr = VisualRecognitionV3(
        '2019-04-30',
        url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api',
        iam_apikey='<API KEY>'
    )

    result_json = watson_vr.classify(
        images_file=bytes_img,
        threshold=0.1,
        classifier_ids=['default']
    ).get_result()
```

Thanks

Comment: I guess you have something like `with io.BytesIO(<memory buffer>) as images_file`, which should be OK. Please share your actual `io.BytesIO` code so we can work out what is wrong. Does your image in memory actually have the .jpg mime-type?

Comment: I've edited the original post to add code that illustrates what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```py
bytes_img = byte_stream.getbuffer()
...
result_json = watson_vr.classify(
        images_file=bytes_img,
        threshold=0.1,
        classifier_ids=['default']
    ).get_result()
```

or

```py
with byte_stream as images_file:
    result_json = watson_vr.classify(
        images_file=images_file,
        threshold='0.1',
        classifier_ids=['default']
    ).get_result()
```

Comment: The only significant difference I can see is calling getbuffer() rather than getvalue(). When I try this, I get back the error: "ValueError: images_filename must be provided". 
As mentioned above, when I supply a filename, I get the error: "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'float'".This is basically when I was getting before. If it helps, the ibm_watson package I'm working with is v3.0.3.